# iOS 7 UIScrollView height not change

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

On an iPhone I have a UIViewController with a UIScrollView and I am having problems setting the height.

```
[_scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
//[_scrollView setContentSize:_viewController.frame.size];

_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width, 700);

NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", _scrollView.frame.size.height]);
```

NSLog reports 574.000000
I have done this on iPad development and works fine

Comment: Why would changing the scroll view's content size affect the frame's height?

Comment: What does this tell you? It's contentSize instead of frame.  `NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", _scrollView.contentSize.height]);`

Comment: Also, what is the actual problem?

Comment: I want to increase the height, need more room

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the frame of the scroll view bigger, use

```
[_scrollView setFrame:newfram];
```

If you want to set the scrolling area inside the scrollView to be bigger, use

```
[_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width, _scrollView.frame.size.height + 300)];     // ) was missing
```

the previous example **adds 300 pixels** of extra space to the scroll view. The scroll view will only scroll how you are expecting if the content size is larger than the frame.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but many things works without the use of auto layout, and I notice that on the Apples examples is disabled too. I hard to find information on how to deal with this with Auto Layout Enabled. -

Answer (score 0):

The NSLog is correct.  The `frame.height` and `contentSize.height` properties relate to two different things...

You can think of `scrollView.frame.height` as the size of the frame in which content appears.

Then consider `scrollView.contentSzie.height` to be the size of the content displayed within the frame

Hope this helps